# Multiple documentation notebooks open at the same time

Tags: front-end, notebooks

Is it possible to view multiple documentation notebooks at the same time without launching multiple kernels? I'm sure it must be possible.

Comment: Shift-F1 works on Windows. Or right-click on a link in the documentation notebook and select "Open in new window".

Comment: On OS X that doesn't work

Comment: Shift-F1 works on Linux

Answer (score 5):

It can done in OS X, but AFAIK only from a previously open Documentation Center notebook. If you have one open, then you can do it this way.

1. Run your mouse cursor over any hyperlink in the Documentation Center notebook.
2. Bring up the context menu. (right-click or ctrl-left-click)
3. Select **Open in New Window**.

[image: help_windows]

Comment: On OS X, I get a new Doc Ctr window from the menu: Help > Wolfram Documentation.  Doing it multiple times yields multiple windows.

Comment: @MichaelE2. +1. Didn't know about that. Can't remember the last time I opened the Documentation Center from the Help menu :-) Certainly never tried to do it twice in the same session.